# listing EC2 instances by wildcard with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to list all instances that have a name containing *loadtest*.

I've tried various forms of `filter` and `filters` unsuccessfully
What I have so far is:

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
ec2.describe_instances.each do |page|
  page.reservations.each do |reservation|
    reservation.instances.each do |instance|
      puts instance.tags
      puts instance.state
      puts instance.state.name
    end 
  end 
end
```

I wish to get a hash similar to :

```
{Name: loadtest-1west, id: <someid>, state: running}
{Name: loadtest-10west, id: <someid>, state: stopped}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `Name` tag on your instances, the `describe_instances` call would look like this:

```
ec2.describe_instances({
  filters: [{ name: 'tag:Name', values: ['loadtest*'] }]
})
```

For tags, the filter name is `tag:<name-of-tag>`.

You can just iterate through the response and output the fields you want (example without pagination):

```
def name_tag(tags)
  name = tags.select {|t| t.key == 'Name'}
  name[0].value if name.length > 0
end

ec2.describe_instances({
  filters: [{ name: 'tag:Name', values: ['loadtest*'] }]
}).reservations.each do |reservation|
  reservation['instances'].each do |instance|
    name = name_tag(instance.tags)
    puts "{Name: #{name}, id: #{instance.instance_id}, state: #{instance.state.name}}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This works. I'll be studying this to see why it works though.